# Funcion recursiva en haskell

Tags: haskell

Tengo que hacer un tp en Haskell y me falta solo este ejercicio y no puedo resolverlo, alguien me puede ayudar, tiene que ser recursiva

Implementar recursivamente la función `divisoresMenores :: Int −> Int` que dado `n` natural, calcula la cantidad de números naturales menores o iguales a `n` que lo dividen.

Hice el ejercicio en haskell con dos funciones y así corre bien; pero lo tengo que hacer con recursión. Ahí está el problema, no me sale, y también lo hice con una lista y no sé si va. A continucaion subo el ejercicio para ver si alguien lo puede modificar a recursivo. Sería una gran ayuda para mí.

```
divisoresMenores :: Int -> Int
divisoresMenores = length.divisores

divisores:: Int -> [Int]
divisores n = [m | m <- [1..n], n `mod` m == 0]
```

Comment: Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo. ["¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hice el ejercicio en haskell cons dos funcionea y asi corre bien, pero lo tengo que hacer con recursion ahi esta el problema no me sale, y también lo chice con una lista y no se si va, a continucaion subo el ejercicio para ver si alguien lo           puede modificar a recursivo , seria una gran ayuda para mi                     
divisoresMenores :: Int -> Int
divisoresMenores = length.divisores

divisores:: Int -> [Int]
divisores n = [m | m <- [1..n], n `mod` m == 0]

Answer (score 0):

Con funciones recursivas siempre hay que tener en cuenta dos cosas:

- cómo reducir el problema en cada llamada a la función
- cuál es la condición final o de parada para acabar la recursión

Como norma y por claridad, es mejor usar una función auxiliar que acarree de algún modo el resultado en cada iteración.

```hs
divisoresMenores :: Int -> Int
divisoresMenores n = aux n
  where aux m = ...
```

Para reducir el problema, la idea es poner la llamada `aux m` en función de `aux (m-1)`, algo así:

```hs
aux m | n `mod` m == 0 = 1 + aux (m-1)
      | otherwise = aux (m-1)
```

Como condición final:

```hs
aux 1 = 1
```

Combinando todo y puliendo un poco:

```hs
divisoresMenores :: Int -> Int
divisoresMenores n = aux n
  where aux m | m < 1 = 0
              | n `mod` m == 0 = 1 + aux (m-1)
              | otherwise      = aux (m-1)
```

El problema de las funciones recursivas es que puedes llenar el *stack* de llamadas si se hacen demasiadas. Una optimización es pasar un acumulador en cada llamada de modo que no haga falta guardar nada en el *stack* (el compilador se encarga de hacer la optimización):

```hs
divisoresMenores :: Int -> Int
divisoresMenores n = aux n 1
  where aux m acc | m <= 1 = acc
                  | n `mod` m == 0 = aux (m-1) (acc+1)
                  | otherwise      = aux (m-1) acc
```